# the primitive of $f(x)=\frac {x^{2009}} {(1+x^2)^{1006}}$ with respect to x is $\frac {1} {n} (\frac {x^2} {1+x^2})^{m}$ then find m and n.

Tags: integration, functions

the primitive of $$f(x)=\frac {x^{2009}} {(1+x^2)^{1006}}$$ with respect to x is $$\frac {1} {n} (\frac {x^2} {1+x^2})^{m}$$ then find m and n.

**My Approach**

I am not able to understand how to recreate the form that is asked because clearly applying by parts to reduce the power won't work.

Comment: Start by applying the definition of primitive.

Answer (score 3):

Recall that a primitive (or antiderivative) of some function $f$ is a differentiable function $F$ satisfying $F'=f$.

A primitive, if one exists, is never unique. In fact, if $F,G$ are primitives of $f$, Then $F'-G'=0$, which is equivalent to $(F-G)'=0$. It is not difficult to see that the only differentiable functions with $0$ derivative are constant functions. Therefore we see that a primitive is unique up to a constant. This justifies the usual notation you might have seen $\int f(x)dx= F(x)+C$.

Now, for the current problem, it might be difficult to understand why the primitive of $f$ might look like $F(x):=\tfrac{1}{n} \left(\tfrac{x^2}{1+x^2}\right)^m$, but you don't really need to do this to solve the problem. You just need to find $n,m$ such that $F'(x)=f(x)$ holds for all $x$.

So $F'(x)=\tfrac{m}{n} \left(\tfrac{x^2}{1+x^2}\right)^{m-1} \tfrac{2x\cdot(1+x^2)-x^2\cdot(2x)}{(1+x^2)^2}$ using the chain rule and the computation for the derivative of a quotient of functions. This simplifies to $F'(x)=\tfrac{m}{n}\tfrac{2x^{2m-1}}{(1+x^2)^{m+1}}$.

So we want that $\tfrac{m}{n}\tfrac{2x^{2m-1}}{(1+x^2)^{m+1}}=\tfrac{x^{2009}}{(1+x^2)^{1006}}$. This suggest taking $m=1005$ and $n=2010$.

Then $\tfrac{1005}{2010} \tfrac{2x^{2\cdot1005 -1}}{(1+x^2)^{1005+1}}=\tfrac{x^{2009}}{(1+x^2)^{1006}}$ indeed and we are done.

All primitives of $f$, in this case, take the form $\tfrac{1}{2010} \left(\tfrac{x^2}{1+x^2}\right)^{1005}+C$.

If one wanted to solve this directly by integrating, let us consider the class of functions $g(x)=\tfrac{x^{2k-1}}{(1+x^2)^{k+1}}$ for natural numbers $k$.

We can rewrite such a $g$ as $g(x)=\tfrac{1}{2}\tfrac{2x}{(1+x^2)^2}\left(\tfrac{x^2}{1+x^2}\right)^{k-1}$. The crucial observation is that $\left(\tfrac{x^2}{1+x^2}\right)'=\tfrac{2x}{(1+x^2)^2}$.

Therefore, by doing a variable change $u=\tfrac{x^2}{1+x^2}$, we see that $\int g(x) dx=\int \tfrac{1}{2} u^{k-1} u'dx=\tfrac{1}{2}\int u^{k-1} du =\tfrac{1}{2k} u^k + C =\tfrac{1}{2k} \left(\tfrac{x^2}{1+x^2}\right)^k+ C$.

Comment: I understand but is there any way we could solve the integral instead of differentiating?

Comment: Edited the answer to include that. Just take $k=1005$.

Answer (score 2):

*The
other way*

Using the Gaussian hypergeometric function,
$$I=\int \frac {x^{a}} {(1+x^2)^{b}}\,dx=\frac{x^{a+1} }{a+1}\,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{a+1}{2},b;\frac{a+3}{2};-x^2\right)$$
Expanded as a series
$$I=\frac{x^{a+1} }{a+1}\left(1-\frac{(a+1) b }{a+3}x^2+O\left(x^4\right)\right)$$

Doing the same for the other piece

$$\frac 1n\left(\frac{x^2}{x^2+1}\right)^m=\frac 1 nx^{2m}\left(1-m x^2+O\left(x^4\right)\right)$$

Just compare the first terms.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $y=\dfrac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}$:

$$\begin{align*}
\int f(x) \, dx &= \int \frac{x^{2009}}{\left(1+x^2\right)^{1006}} \, dx \\
&= \int \frac{\sqrt{\frac{1-y}{1+y}} \left(\frac{1-y}{1+y}\right)^{1004}}{\left(1+\frac{1-y}{1+y}\right)^{1006}} \cdot -\sqrt{\frac{1+y}{1-y}} \, \frac{dy}{(1+y)^2} \\
&= - \frac1{2^{2006}} \int (1-y)^{1004} \, dy \\
& \,\,\vdots
\end{align*}$$